# Dataspell outputs the following error: Local cdn resources have problems on chrome/safari when used in jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook, pyvis, dataspell

faced with such an error: Local cdn resources have problems on chrome/safari when used in jupyter-notebook.
It appears when working with the pyvis library.

```
net = Network(notebook=True)

net.add_nodes(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],  # node ids
    label=['Node #1', 'Node #2', 'Node #3', 'Node #4', 'Node #5'],  # node labels
    # node titles (display on mouse hover)
    title=['Main node', 'Just node', 'Just node', 'Just node', 'Node with self-loop'],
    color=['#d47415', '#22b512', '#42adf5', '#4a21b0', '#e627a9']  # node colors (HEX)
)
net.add_edges([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (5, 1)])

net.show('graph.html')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVbAa.png)

I tried switching the browser to dataspell

Comment: What do you mean by "local CDN"? I don't see anything loaded from a CDN here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `pyvis` [documentation](https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#using-pyvis-within-jupyter-notebook):

> while using notebook in chrome browser, to render the graph, pass additional kwarg ‘cdn_resources’ as ‘remote’ or ‘inline’

I did `net = Network(notebook=True, cdn_resources='in_line')`

A note from me - you have to use 'in_line' instead of 'inline'. From [sources](https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis/blob/master/pyvis/network.py):

```py
assert cdn_resources in ["local", "in_line", "remote"], "cdn_resources not in [local, in_line, remote]."
```

Additionally, `pyvis` output render is an open feature request for DataSpell at the moment. Watch and upvote this ticket if you're interested: [DS-3446](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-3446/Using-pyvis-in-Jupyter-notebook)

Comment: I get a `TemplateNotFound: lib/vis-9.1.2/vis-network.css` error